# Vue3 Project Google Analytics

Tags: vue.js, google-analytics

I've been looking around and couldn't find a straightforward tutorial or almost anything on

*how to display google analytics data on eg. an admin page on a website.*

So my question is, **how to go about to fetch/get the previously connected website's Google Analytics datasets, in vue**?

I am using the latest GA4 platform to collect the data from this very website, that I'm trying to fetch (back) the analytics data to.

Is there a plugin maybe, or just plain javascript?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this link can help you : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js?hl=en ? Instead of using library or package, try explore Google API's analytics.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code in index.html

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript>
  <iframe
    src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=<%= gtmId %>"
    style="display: none; visibility: hidden"
   ></iframe>
</noscript>
```

https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/devguides/install-tag-manager?hl=ko

Comment: Bro I'm looking for a way, to fetch data from my GA4 analytics. So I'm not looking for how to put data, or in other words measure analytics of my webapp, I am looking for how to present that measured data, on that same website.
So far I've only found some info as to how to do it, by using php, python, node js etc, but not as to how to do it in simple javascript.